# SQL Ordering and Adding a Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, row, distinct

Here's my SQL code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CASE 
       WHEN RS != '' 
          THEN RS 
          ELSE 'Unspecified RS' 
    END AS 'RS Name'
FROM 
    OutstandingClaims
```

It'll return

```
Alexa
Bob
Cary
Dylan
...
Unspecified RS
...
etc.
```

I want to have the entry "All" at the top of this list. Is there a way I can do that without renaming people?

Comment: What 'All' entry?  The 'Unspecified RS'?

Comment: No Unspecified is just for when there's no one there.

Comment: Do you want to add "All" automatically to the output?

Comment: I just want "All" at the top. I'm making a drop list that depends on SQL queries. When the user selects "All" in the drop list, another SQL code snipit will know what to do with that.

Comment: Yes no matter what I want "All" at the top of the output.

Comment: You should really add that in your UI (not from DB)

Comment: Yeah I did originally. But there's a weird error when I try to layer my lists. I think that is the reason. (List layering where another list depends on another.)

Comment: UNION your required value to the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 'All' AS 'RS Name'
union all
SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN RS <> '' 
                     THEN RS 
                     ELSE 'Unspecified RS' 
                END 
FROM OutstandingClaims
```

Comment: But it will not sort the records as required.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add an extra column for sorting

```
SELECT 'All' AS [RS Name], 0 AS sort
UNION
SELECT CASE WHEN RS != '' 
         THEN RS 
         ELSE 'Unspecified RS' 
       END AS [RS Name],
       1 AS sort
FROM OutstandingClaims
ORDER BY sort, [RS Name]
```

Note that UNION returns distinct records by default. No DISTINCT keyword required.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure about what exactly you are asking. But if you just need to display 'All' string **always** at the top,then you can use union and another column to order them all.

So,

```
Select x.rsname from( select 'All' AS rsname, 1 as order
  union
  select distinct (case when RS != '' then RS else 'Unspecified RS' end) AS rsname, 2 as order
 from 
OutstandingClaims) x order by x.order
```